# Get Image/ImageUrl From Subcategory

Tags: magento-1.9

This should be fairly straight forward to do but i can't get the image i've had a look around an peoples methods of getting a sub category is a bit different than mine so can't really apply it anyway the below is what i'm working with i can get the sub category names fine but i need the images or the urls for them.

```
<?php
 $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories(6);
 foreach ($children as $category) { 
  echo '<div class = "sub_cat_item">';
  echo $category->getName();
  echo $category->getImageUrl();  
  echo '</div>';
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', 6);

        foreach ($categories as $cat) {
           echo '<div class = "sub_cat_item">';
           $entity_id = $cat->getId();
           $name = $cat->getName();
           $url_key = $cat->getUrlKey();
           $url_path = $cat->getUrlPath();
           $skin_url = $cat->getImageUrl(); 
           echo '<img src="'.$skin_url.'" />';
           echo '</div>';
    }
```